# How to find/update/get the all obgect field without use id

Tags: mongodb

How can I find/update/get the "items" field without use id please (see the picture)

[image]

Comment: Please see [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

db.collection("800").deleteMany( { items: { $exists : true} })

i find the answer